# PHP cURL send oauth2.0 access_token in header and POST json data

Tags: php, json, post, curl, oauth-2.0

Im trying to send my access_token to oauth2.0 in `POST` header, while at the same time POSTing json in the body.

So I already acquired my access_token, and now want to use it to submit some data to the API.

```
$token = array(
 "access_token" =>$test->access_token);

$data = array(
  "Action" =>"updateUser",
  "data" =>array('somedata' => 'somemoredata')
  );

// Submit some data
$test2=curl_req2($pageURL.$webroot."/api/v1/User.php",$token, $data , "POST");
print_r($test2);
```

The `curl_req2()` function looks like this:

```
function curl_req2($path,$token,$data,$req)
{
    $ch = curl_init($path);
    $data = json_encode($data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token['access_token']));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //$result = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

If I do it this way, it seams like the json code is not recieved. When I `print_r($_REQUEST)` on server side, it simply returns an empty array. If I don't `json_encode` the `$data`, my array gets returned fine.

I then tried adding `'Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)`, to the HTTPHEADER array in curl, but then the authorization in HTTP header does not work.

Is there a way I can both authorize the token in POST headers, while at the same time sending json data in POST body?

Comment: Adding the content type header should not interefere with the Authorization header unless that is the intended functionality of the service.  Please can you show us how you added the Content-Type headers by updating the code in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server's `$_REQUEST` superglobal works with [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), not with JSON data.

If you want to access the request body, you can use:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```